# Nodejs как передать ID в адресную строку сайта

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, express

Всем привет, работаю в Node.js + Express + PostgreSQL и сейчас пытаюсь вывести в адресную строку своего сайта ID который получу с запроса БД, но как-то не могу разобраться как это сделать.

Хочу, чтобы было, что-то типо localhost:3000/ins_log/и тут ID который получу с БД.

Запрос, который пытаюсь реализовать ниже

```
    app.post("/ins_log",urlencodedParser,function(req,res) {
    var config = {
        user:'postgres',
        database:'my',
        password: '1',
        host:'localhost',
        port:5432,
        max:10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config)

    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        if(err){
            return console.error('Соединение не удалось')
        }   
    client.query('select id_table from mytable($1)',[req.body.login], function(err, result) {
        done()
        if (err){
            res.end()
            return console.error("Запрос не удался")
       }
        res.render('ins_log',{pup:result}) 


})
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Современные фронт фреймворки для изменения строки URL используют объект [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API). Но мне кажется, что в Вашей задаче нужно пойти от обратного, то есть сделать запрос по ID из роута. Больше можно сказать зная детали Вашей задачи.